# Polygon Area Postgres

Tags: postgresql, polygon, area

Can I have a polygon-column in Postgres?
Is there a function to calculate the area of the polygon or at least the area of the bounding box?
(without postgis)

Thanks

EDIT:
area(path(w.poly)) works.  Is it the same?

Comment: "Is it the same?" - same as what? You said you're not installing Postgis.

Comment: area(path(w.poly)) works without postgis, but is this the area of the polygon? or is it wrong?

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-geometry.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say `area(path(w.poly))` works.

It calculates the area of a polygon or other geometric figure.   It is correct.